# Server-to-Client: RMI and 2 JVM's (Distinct Computers)

Tags: communication, rmi

I'm using RMI for a while now, and i would like to know:

- Is there a way that a RMI-SERVER can notify a RMI-CLIENT that his avaiable (online), passing his ip/port that should be used in Naming.list() in client's code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not within RMI. You could look into UDP multicast, or the JNI Discovery and Lookup Service, which is just a massive layer over the top (in all senses) of multicast.